# Why frame border / line appear after click text widget (the frame is inside canvas) tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

i've the problem for make an GUI apps with python tkinter.

here is my sample code

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry('300x300')

root.title('CSV Editor')

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)

notebook.pack(pady=10, expand=True)

tab_home = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=300, height=300)

notebook.add(tab_home, text='Home')

fr_home = tk.Frame(tab_home, background="white")

fr_home.grid(row=0, column=0)

fr_home_container_canvas = tk.Frame(fr_home, background="red")

fr_home_container_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nw')

fr_home_container_canvas.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

fr_home_container_canvas.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

fr_home_container_canvas.grid_propagate(False)

canvas_home = tk.Canvas(fr_home_container_canvas)

canvas_home.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

vsb = tk.Scrollbar(fr_home_container_canvas, orient="vertical", command=canvas_home.yview)

vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')

canvas_home.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

fr_home_widget_canvas = tk.Frame(canvas_home, background="yellow")

canvas_home.create_window((0, 0), window=fr_home_widget_canvas, anchor='nw')

fr_home_widget_canvas.config(width=300, height=300, padx=10)

fr_home_container_canvas.config(width=300, height=300)

canvas_home.config(scrollregion=canvas_home.bbox("all"))


text_widget = tk.Text(fr_home_widget_canvas, width = 30, height = 10)

text_widget.grid(column=0, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

if i run this code, this is the preview
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr1Vj.png)

but when i click inside the text widget, in the frame appear line / border like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJJCC.png)

What is that line / border? how to remove it?

thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

It is the highlight background which can be removed by setting `highlightthickness=0`:

```py
canvas_home = tk.Canvas(fr_home_container_canvas, highlightthickness=0)
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, thank you so much!!
problem is solved with your advice :) :)

Comment: @DiazAdi If it solves your problem, consider to accept it as the answer.

Comment: thanks  @acw1668. This solved my problem too. It is a pitty that I cant accept it as the answer.